# How to get sliders to represent lower $\leq x < y < z \leq$ upper?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, slider

Let `lower` and `upper` be fixed constants, with `lower` < `upper`.

Now, suppose that `x`, `y`, and `z` represent *any* numbers that satisfy these constraints:

$lower \leq x < y < z \leq upper$

I'm looking for a way to represent such numbers `x`, `y`, and `z` in a `Manipulate` widget.

The ideal solution would be a single slider over the range [`lower`, `upper`], and having three knobs, one for each of `x`, `y`, and `z`, such that each knob is free to slide over the sub-interval defined by the neighboring sliders and the bounds `lower` and `upper`.

The [`IntervalSlider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html) control gets me almost there, but it has only two knobs.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a different object to control some variables?  It's not exactly a Manipulate control but it can have the same effect:

```
HorizontalGauge[Dynamic@{x, y, z}, {0, 100}]
```

[image: Gauge]

I haven't worked out the constraining of variables but this could be a useful start.

Comment: How about: `Column[ {
  HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[{x, y, z},
    Function[{val},
     {x, y, z} = Sort[val]
     ]
    ],
   {0, 100}
   ],
  Dynamic[{x, y, z}]}
 ]`

Answer (score 4):

A teeny modification to Smit's solution, to fit the requirements of the question:

```
With[{lower = 0, higher = 1},
 Column[
  {HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[{x, y, z}, 
     Function[{val}, {x, y, z} = Sort[val]]], {lower, higher},
     ImageSize -> 400], 
   Dynamic[{x, y, z}]}]
 ]
```